# matchMedia calls functions twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, matchmedia

I am trying to use a function on mobile devices (less than 700px in this example) and another function on large devices. I use matchMedia in the following way:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 700px)");
mql.addListener(handleResize);
handleResize(mql);
function handleResize(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {      
    $(".button").on("click", function(){
        $(".hidden").slideToggle();
    })                 
  } else {  
    $(".button").on("click", function(){
        $(".hidden").fadeToggle();
    })   
  }
}
```

At first, the code behaves as expected, the problem occurs when I resize the window. For instance, if the window first loads under 700px and then is resized to more than 700px, the button fires fade first, then slide and vice versa. What I want to achieve off course is calling only slide on large sreens and only fade on small screens. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: use your code inside resize handler...

Comment: thank you for replying, but could you please clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time the `handleResize` callback fires, it attaches another **click** event to the button. To prevent attaching a ton of events, you have to first remove it with `off()`.

Here is an example that accomplishes what you wanted:

```
var $hidden = $('.hidden');
var $btn = $('button');
var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 700px)");

function bindSlide() {
  // Using `off()` is required in order not to end up attaching a lot of callbacks
  $btn.off("click.mql").on("click.mql", function() {
    $hidden.stop().slideToggle();
  }); 
}

function bindFade() {
  $btn.off("click.mql").on("click.mql", function() {
    $hidden.stop().fadeToggle();
  }); 
}

function handleScreen(mql) {
  if (mql.matches) {       
    bindSlide();
  } else {
    bindFade();
  }
}

// Handle media query 'change' event
mql.addListener(handleScreen);
handleScreen(mql);
```

Please note that `window.matchMedia` isn't supported by all Browsers. For Browsers that don't support matchMedia natively you can use a polyfill: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/rhkLng9o

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time! Would you mind explaining one detail? What is "click.mql" inside of .off and .on? Is it some sort of custom event? I noticed the code doesn´t work when I delete the ".mql" part. Thanks!!

Comment: It's jQuery's way of namespacing events. It's a good practice because when you remove an event like this `$btn.off('click')` it will remove all click handlers from that element. However, when you add a suffix such as **.something** and you remove that event using the suffix like `$btn.off('click.something')`, it will remove only those handlers and not all of them. More here: http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names