# Chrome matchMedia listener firing twice on resize

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, media-queries, matchmedia

I have the below function in my code, I'd like to fire off a function when the device window/viewport is less than 768px wide. This function fires on page load (hence the query outside the listener), during testing in Chrome, I find that the listener fires twice on resize, returning first a false then followed by a true. This is despite the fact that the window/viewport never drops below 768px in width. When conducting the same test in Firefox, it seems to behave correctly.

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so what was your solution?

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");

if (!mql.matches) {
    myFunction();
};

mql.addListener(function(device) {
    if(!device.matches) {
        myFunction();
    }
});
```

N.B. In Chrome I was testing in 'Device Mode' selecting 'Apple iPad 3/4' and in Firefox I was using 'Responsive Design View' running at 768x1024

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, sorry

Comment: Thanks for the reply @InvernoMuto. That's interesting, so you're saying yours is behaving as expected? I am beginning to think it could be an issue with my Chrome emulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matchMedia calls functions twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441314/matchmedia-calls-functions-twice)